# Linq to XML dynamic order by options

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new to linq and I've found so many different ways to build the queries.  I wanted to post this to show the code that I'm currently working with and try to tackle two issues.

1. Being able to dynamically pass in asc/desc

   a.  In some cases I want to be able to sort each attribute in different asc/desc order
2. Be able to dynamically pass in the number of order by parameters

   a.  In the code below, I'm passing multiple attributes for each item that I want to order by.  Obviously, I'd rather pass in a collection and then allow the code to build the order by based on that collection.  I can pass the collection in, but I'm not sure how I'd build the order by from that collection.

   b.  I also think that the sort type will come into play at some point, so I'm not sure how I'd be able to know how to dynamically cast as well?

Thanks for any input.

```
    Private Function XMLSort(ByVal xOldDom As XmlDocument, ByVal sChildNodeName As String, ByVal sOrderByAttributeName1 As String, ByVal sOrderByAttributeName2 As String, ByVal sOrderByAttributeName3 As String) As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
         Dim xOldDocument As New XDocument
         xOldDocument = XDocument.Parse(xOldDom.OuterXml)

         Dim oQuery As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
         oQuery = From xNode In xOldDocument.Descendants(sChildNodeName) _
                  Order By CInt(xNode.Attribute(sOrderByAttributeName1)), CInt(xNode.Attribute(sOrderByAttributeName2)), CStr(xNode.Attribute(sOrderByAttributeName3)) _
                  Select xNode

         Return oQuery
    End Function
```

Comment: What exactly is the reason for this dynamic sorting? Is it just the different parts of your program need different sorting? Or do you get the required sorting from the user? If that's the case, what form do you or can you get them from the user?

Comment: Different parts of the application need different sorting.  I'm using third-party assemblies to return information and need to sort that information based on the requirements before sending it to the View.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best option would be: just do it. When you have the collection and know the required order at compile time, just use LINQ to order it. I think, you can't do much better, you would have to express the order in some way and LINQ is as comfortable as it gets.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks.  I'm currently creating a sort function for each XML that I have to return.  I was just trying to consolidate those functions to be able to pass in the xml and what to sort on and allow it to sort.